# UIWebView not scrollable

Tags: ios, xamarin

I am trying to embed a webview into navController, but end up with webview not scrollable at all.

The webpage regardless of its size will not allow to be scrolled. What am I doing wrong here?

```
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using System.Drawing;

namespace TestNamespace
{
    public class Level2ViewController : UIViewController
    {
        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            Title = "Test";
            UIWebView webview = new UIWebView (View.Bounds);
            View.AddSubview(webview);
            webview.LoadRequest (new NSUrlRequest (new NSUrl("https://news.google.com/")));
        }

        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
        }
    }


    // The UIApplicationDelegate for the application. This class is responsible for launching the
    // User Interface of the application, as well as listening (and optionally responding) to application events from iOS.
    [Register ("AppDelegate")]
    public class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
    {
        // class-level declarations

        UIWindow window;
        UINavigationController navController;

        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
        {
            window = new UIWindow ();
            window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();
            navController = new UINavigationController ();

            Level2ViewController new1 = new Level2ViewController();

            // push the view controller onto the nav controller and show the window
            navController.PushViewController(new1, false);
            window.RootViewController = navController;
            window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

            return true;
        }

        public override void OnResignActivation (UIApplication application)
        {
            // Invoked when the application is about to move from active to inactive state.
            // This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) 
            // or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
            // Games should use this method to pause the game.
        }

        public override void DidEnterBackground (UIApplication application)
        {
            // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers and store the application state.
            // If your application supports background exection this method is called instead of WillTerminate when the user quits.
        }

        public override void WillEnterForeground (UIApplication application)
        {
            // Called as part of the transiton from background to active state.
            // Here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
        }

        public override void OnActivated (UIApplication application)
        {
            // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. 
            // If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
        }

        public override void WillTerminate (UIApplication application)
        {
            // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data, if needed. See also DidEnterBackground.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this in ViewDidLoad

```
webiew.ScrollView.ScrollEnabled = true;
webView.ScalesPageToFit = true;
```